# AES256 decryption problem with PKCS7 Padding

Tags: apex, crypto, decrypt

I have an encrypted token(Encrypted in Java system with AES256 algorithm and PKCS7 padding).

when I try to decrypt in SF using crypto class. some of the information is missing from the original token.

As Crypto class supports PKCS5 padding, I doubt this is the problem.
Any help will be highly appreciated how to decrypt correctly using PKCS7 padding in SF. Following is the sample code I'm using

> String beforeEncryption =
> '{"UserId":12345,"Role":"testRole","LicenceNumber":"123456789","EmiartesId":"784198012345678","LicenceAuthority":"test","Expiry":"2020-11-13T15:27:16.6847792+04:00"}';

> String encrypted =
> 'D7dEjNTmJdbQDbNokTwiwaWqetSDnXnxH4+Eqzi34sRvyl/jOqLud6IQKYU3kylgUQCFsib6eENaq2KLhXx/fgChPIXCCGZMsw+/Euo2z9ZVzjk0Kq4VzP3LWb1GRHl4ygJJ8f2GN/JgBBZiyqAXb3CHKBjwwxHddZLkxvX7WcHyX9Odvt3Eh+fmbw6jJtPWH5lKBSx2jOQSAsBjaMENbqDU7Rqhg9p4Eq21zoXvRoI=';

```
Blob decodedEncryptedText=EncodingUtil.base64Decode(encrypted);
Blob cryptoKey=Blob.valueOf('NW7LbO3xdUmXZEIvjYkzxA==AxC0Eh1o');
Blob decryptedData = Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV('AES256',cryptoKey,decodedEncryptedText);

system.Debug('--valuee'+decryptedData.toString());
//After decrypting in Apex using apex crypto method
```

> Decrypted text =
> '"Role":"testRole","LicenceNumber":"123456789","EmiartesId":"784198012345678","LicenceAuthority":"test","Expiry":"2020-11-13T15:27:16.6847792+04:00"}'

***Issue:*** `{"UserId":12345,` is missing in the decrypted text.

Comment: The paddings and their equivalence are explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53941878/can-i-use-pkcs5padding-padding-algorithm-while-decryption-for-already-encrypted . Your question doesn't contain a [Minimum, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so it's hard to tell what's going on. If you think of your question as a unit test, you're showing the observed scenario but you're missing the setup of the test and the expected result.  Please take the [Tour](/tour) and see [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) for more info.

Comment: @identigral
Updated the body with an example

Comment: Thanks for the edit. While a minor issue, it would be helpful if you formatted your changes - see [How do I format my post](/help/formatting) for details. More to the point, you've got a partial sketch of a Minimum, Reproducible Example. The encryption step (even if it's non-Salesforce code) is still missing. It's important because you claim that the issue is related to padding but there's no proof you've encrypted it correctly (with whatever padding, algorithm, block size, ...).

Comment: Is it possible to ask java team to change padding, or expose an API to decrypt the same? Or if you're using middle ware if that can do the job

Comment: @YsrShk
The JAVA system is a generic system, they can't change their encryption methodology only for SF as it was used to integrate with several other systems as well.